# Create variable of unknown type automatically if it doesn't exist?

Tags: python, abaqus

I have different variables of an unknown type (in ABAQUS, it says "Sequence") and want to combine them through a loop:

```
a = [[unknown type], [unknown type], ...]
x = []
for i in a:
    x.append(i)
```

The problem now is that when I initialize x with = [] I get the error message

> TypeError: Can only concatenate list (not "Sequence") to list.

Is there another (simple/efficient) way, e.g. to automatically create x in the first loop?

Comment: You're looking for a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)...

Comment: That would assume `list` is the only type that has an `append` method; otherwise, how would Python know to assume `x = []`, rather than `x = SomeOtherThingWithAppend()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
x = [v for v in a]
```